# Load block programmatically, result: <drupal-render-placeholder

Tags: 8, blocks

I want to load a block programmatically:

```
$block = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('block')->load('contextualcart');
$block = \Drupal::entityManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);
$blockMarkup = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($block);
```

But the result is:

```
<drupal-render-placeholder callback="Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::lazyBuilder" arguments="0=velocontextualcart&amp;1=full&amp;2" token="5IaX-v_M8zGkro6F9hTE93zRfIj9p4nHeLFv8Ja6ZW0"></drupal-render-placeholder>
```

This is fine, because I have to insert a block in AJAX.

What happened? How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try without rendering? Ajax callbacks can return unrendered build arrays.

Comment: Yes, don't work.
I resolve :
$block = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$block = $block->createInstance('block_contextual_cart')->build();
$blockMarkup = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($block);

Answer (score 4):

When calling [`->render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3Arender/8.4.x) it is rendering a structured array tree assuming that it is part of a whole page which will then do placeholder replacements later.

Use [`renderRoot()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Renderer.php/function/Renderer%3A%3ArenderRoot/8.4.x) if you are the last instance and e.g. return this directly as an AJAX or JsonResponse.

Answer (score 1):

The following code solved the issue:

```
$block = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$block = $block->createInstance('block_contextual_cart')->build();
$blockMarkup = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($block);
```

<sup>Source: [@BOES comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/241298/load-block-programmatically-result-drupal-render-placeholder#comment295310_241298).</sup>